# I cannot type "\" on Xcode with my mac pro(2018)

Tags: xcode

My mac pro has "\" on the keybaord(it's printed on the keybord on the upper right side), however, whenever I try typing it, it appears on Xcode as "korean won" mark. 
it's the same when I transfer my keyboard to Korean or to English...

I can't make a proper code without "\" :(
please help.

Comment: Can you type \ in any program on your Mac or is the issue just with Xcode?

Comment: it's the only issue with Xcode.

Comment: Not sure if alt-codes work on mac, but it's worth a shot. Try alt + 92 https://theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-printable-characters/backslash-reverse-slash-ascii-code-92.html

Comment: Check the Key Bindings in Xcode Preferences.